# timezone in .ics file not recognized by outlook generated by iCal4J

Tags: java, outlook, calendar, icalendar

My timezone I set is ignored by outlook.

Here is my .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//TEST//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170208T135427Z
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Tehran:20170124T043000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Tehran:20170131T041000
SUMMARY:Test Event
TZID:Asia/Tehran
LOCATION: Zurich, Switzerland
DESCRIPTION:Lorem ipsum
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
URL:www.google.ch
UID:20170208T135430Z-uidGen@192.168.43.131
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any Ideas why the timezone is not shown in outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iCalendar object does not have a VTIMEZONE component.